Is it possible to see how many documents where used to create a Customer Extractor Model?
I can see how many testing documents the model was evaluated against, but can't see how many documents where used to train the model. Do I just assume that it's all documents, is there a way to view this?
I am wondering because it's possible for the evaluation to be invalid or fail for some documents, could it be the same when training the model?
I viewed the evaluated documents, no option to view model document count.
